# use absolutepath in image element as source

Tags: web-applications, tomcat6, image, absolute-path

i have a simple img element in my jsp page that must use as source an image placed externally to the webapp context...

i did something like this: (the path generated from the servlet and setted using JSTL)

```
<img src="C:/somewhere/32x32/userXX.png" class="member-box-avatar">
```

but what i always get is `http://myhost//myapp/C:/somewhere/32x32/userXX.png` and so the image doesn't show up, is there a way to solve this problem ?

i'm using tomcat6 as server and i've already tryed forward and back slashes

relevant code portion :

```
     <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${empty guest}">
    <img src="${foto}${user.username}.png" class="member-box-avatar" />
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
<img src="img/guest.png" class="member-box-avatar" />                                        
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
```

${foto} contains the absolute path "C:\mypath\32x32\" (i've tryed with any sort of slashes combination)

Comment: solved by placing Context in server.xml file
`<Context path="/userimages" docBase="C:\mypath\32x32\" debug="0" reloadable="true" crossContext="true"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/your/image/dir/image.png">
```

if its hosted on your app context.

Otherwise use

1.IFrame to render image url of other image

2.Asynchronously render image using Ajax / jQuery

Comment: what i get is `http://myhost/MyWebApp/C:/mypath/32x32/userXX.png`...so it seems that is still under the webapp context

Comment: can you share the code you are using (at least important part related to the issue) , which helps

Comment: you cannont share the `physical path` of the file over web. i suggest you to move your images to a path which will reside inside your web-application and then user `request.getContextPath` as suggested to point those

Comment: the problem is that i can't move those file because they are costantly updated from an other service...i was reading something about using the Context tag in server.xml to define an external context accessible from the webapp...any suggestion about it ? when i was on apache i used the aliases to make the trick...is there something similar ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling because of this for hours.
I made it work with this trick.

```
<a href="edit?action=showImageFull&url=C:/Users/Noir/Desktop/WorkSpaceEclipseNeu/w_mvc_3/WebContent/imgfolder/${imgageimage.time}.jpg" target="_parent">
<img  src="http://localhost:8080/w_mvc_3/edit?action=showImageFull&url=C:/Users/Noir/Desktop/WorkSpaceEclipseNeu/w_mvc_3/WebContent/imgfolder/${imgageimage.time}-thumb.jpg"width="150" height="100">
```

Inside your Java Environment

String action = request.getParameter("action");

```
    if(action.equals("showImageFull")) {            
        try {
             String url = request.getParameter("url");

                response.setContentType("image/jpeg");  
                ServletOutputStream out;  
                out = response.getOutputStream();  
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(url);  

                BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);  
                BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);  
                int ch =0; ;  
                while((ch=bin.read())!=-1)  
                {  
                bout.write(ch);  
                }  

                bin.close();  
                fin.close();  
                bout.close();  
                out.close();  

        } catch (BookNotFoundException e) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/error.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }               
    }
```

This is for showing a thumbnail and for showing the full image.
I hope it helps.